# Tensorflow error: In[0] is not a matrix [Op:MatMul]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to classify some numeric data with TensorFlow. I was working on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough#tensorflow_programming) tutorial, but imported some other data out of a csv instead. Running the line

```
predictions = model(features)
```

causes the error

```
InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix [Op:MatMul]
```

when feature is defined as

```
<tf.Tensor: id=8, shape=(1000,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.15328342,...)
```

and

labels as

```
<tf.Tensor: id=9, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'left'>
```

My code is

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
...
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =
train_test_split(df.drop(['label'], axis=1), df["label"], test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((X_train.values,y_train.values)))
dataset.label_name=label_name
dataset.column_names=column_names
dataset.num_epochs=1

features, labels = next(iter(dataset))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2000, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1000,)),  
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2000, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000)
])

predictions = model(features)
predictions[:1000]
```

**Changes**

```
predictions = model.predict(features)

Error when checking input: expected dense_24_input to have shape (1000,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

**It looks like there is a problem with defining my tensors.**

```
print("Features: {}".format(feature_names))
print("Label: {}".format(label_name))
```

returns

```
Features: Index(['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v9', 'v10',
   ...
   'v991', 'v992', 'v993', 'v994', 'v995', 'v996', 'v997', 'v998', 'v999',
   'v1000'],
  dtype='object', length=1000)
Label: label
```

but there is only a single tensor without a name (shape=(1000,))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
predictions = model.predict(features)
```

Comment: This actually did something. Now it says Error when checking input: expected dense_15_input to have shape (1000,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: @Kruspe each one of your features should be a vector with 1000 values.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I (should) have 1000 features. All of them a single float32. If I set 'input_size = (1,)', (which would make no sense to me), it says 'Python int too large to convert to C long'. This does happen also, if I convert to float64. Did I setup my features wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 
I faced the same type of issue, and tryed the same fix. Your neural network is also very similar to the one I've implemented. At a certaint point I got also an error like this

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_15_input to have shape (1000,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

After 1 day of mumbling I've modified my input declaration (just an example, don't focus on the numbers) from

```
x = tf.Variable(np.array([0.060, 0.060, 0.06, 0.040, 0.060]), trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)
```

to (check square brackets!):

```
x = tf.Variable([np.array([0.060, 0.060, 0.06, 0.040, 0.060])], trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)
```

and BAM! Using

```
prediction = model(x)
```

works great! (No idea why)